# How to increment the value of an int variable?

Tags: java, android, increment

I would like to increment the value of an int variable whenever a user taps on a button, but right now the value gets incremented only once.

This is what I use to increment the value of the variable `p`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int p = 1;

    if (p == 9) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You have reached to maximum number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        p = p + 1;                      
        holder.textViewQuantity.setText("" + p);                        
    }
}
```

Comment: move `int p = 1;`  as class member.

Comment: Not sure and not sure why the close votes, it has a clear enough problem with enough code to demonstrate.

Comment: @SteffenKreutz i am using p to increase the qty of product, like i have 3 items in a List, and i left p with 4 for the first list item and now in second list item when i do click on increment button it showing directly 5 instead of 2 ... so its the main problem i am facing

Comment: So, you din't even bother to see answers people give here because it was not your real question ?

Comment: Once again this user struck us with a "too complex" question which, wait for it, is not even his real question. Maybe you, dear OP, start to **explain** what you want and what you have tried so far. In clean and easy to understand sentences. (beside that: setting a value in a viewholder will result in funny results as soon as you scroll your list... you have more issues than increasing a value! ... just saying)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `p` is inside the method it is a *local variable* and is a unique value for each method invocation, initialized as `1` every time.

Moving it to the class it becomes an *instance variable* (AKA field) and maintains its latest value for the length of the life of the class instance.

Read [this doc on the 4 types of variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for more infomation.

```
private int p = 1; //moved 

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(p == 9) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You have reached to maximum number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ;
    }
    else {                              
        p = p+1;                        
        holder.textViewQuantity.setText(""+p);                      
    }
```

Comment: I know but i am using p to increase the qty of product, like i have 3 items in a List, and i left p with 4 for the first list item and now in second list item when i do click on increment button it showing directly 5 instead of 2 ... so its the main problem i am facing

Comment: Well you want to add the quantity (`p`) to the list item class. If that's not suitable, then a new class that contains product class and a quantity is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `p` should be a class member:

```
int p = 1;  

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(p == 9) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You have reached to maximum number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ;
    }
    else {                              
        p = p+1;                        
        holder.textViewQuantity.setText(""+p);                      
    }
```

Comment: I know but i am using p to increase the qty of product, like i have 3 items in a List, and i left p with 4 for the first list item and now in second list item when i do click on increment button it showing directly 5 instead of 2 ... so its the main problem i am facing

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as global variable. Make it visible to the whole class (I assume, you are not declaring the object again and again). At the moment the scope of the variable is limited to the function and this variable gets the value of 1 every time the event occurs.

whenever this event is called, your value p is assigned value 1.

```
class YourClass{

     int p;  /// creating p 
     YourClass(){
      p = 1;     /// initializing the value in constructor;
     } 


 // your onClick Event Code;
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if(p == 9) {
 Toast.makeText(context, "You have reached to maximum number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   return ;
 }
 else {                              
   p = p+1;                        
    holder.textViewQuantity.setText(""+p);                      
 }
 }
```

Comment: I know but i am using p to increase the qty of product, like i have 3 items in a List, and i left p with 4 for the first list item and now in second list item when i do click on increment button it showing directly 5 instead of 2 ... so its the main problem i am facing

Comment: you will hav e to store the counter value with respect to each item..use map here... key will be item and value will be counter

Answer (score 0):

move the int p = 1 out of the function, you're resetting p to 1 onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below :

```
private int p = 1;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(p == 9) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You have reached to maximum number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ;
    }
    else {                              
        p = p+1;                        
        holder.textViewQuantity.setText(""+p);                      
    }
}
```

int p should be a class member.

Comment: I know but i am using p to increase the qty of product, like i have 3 items in a List, and i left p with 4 for the first list item and now in second list item when i do click on increment button it showing directly 5 instead of 2 ... so its the main problem i am facing

Comment: You have to store each item value. Use Map or ArrayList as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your variable static, then it will count all button taps for given class:

```
class Button {
   public static int p = 0;

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub     

   if(p == 9) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "You have reached to maximum number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       return ;
    }
    else {                              
       p = p+1;                        
       holder.textViewQuantity.setText(""+p);                      
    }
}
```

Comment: I know but i am using p to increase the qty of product, like i have 3 items in a List, and i left p with 4 for the first list item and now in second list item when i do click on increment button it showing directly 5 instead of 2 ... so its the main problem i am facing

Answer (score 0):

private int p = 0;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
     p+=1;
   if(p<9)
     holder.textViewQuantity.setText(String.valueof(p)); 
   else
    Toast.makeText(context, "You have reached to maximum number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```